# codeigniter - newline or space

Tags: codeigniter, newline, spacing

possibly it is silly to ask such questions, but really couldn't find any answers for them.

**1-** how to place a newline in view; i.e, " I want to make two lines of codes when they get executed"!!

**2-** how about space; what is the code for spacing between to words or more??

I thought I can use "\n" the same as php, but that didn't work. I also tried break `<br/>`, but without any success. I checked the user guide for codeigniter and it says that **"\n>"** can be used, but surprisingly didn't work.

any idea how to do these things?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this URL : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html

1. echo br(3) produces `<br /><br /><br />`
2. echo nbs(3) produces `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`